# unexpected end of stream exception when deploying to nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to deploy a snapshot jar to a remote nexus repository (Nexus OSS 3.7.1-02).
The server and repositories details are added in settings.xml and distributionManagement added in pom.xml.

The deployment works fine on a nexus repository on localhost. But on the remote repository, only the pom, md5 and sha1 are deployed and the jar deployment fails with the error "unexpected end of stream". Appreciate any help to solve this.

[nexus repository screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od9Nx.gif)

The full stacktrace is as below:

```
    Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project api-core: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project api-core: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject(DeployMojo.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.deployProject(DeployMojo.java:250)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:139)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.proj.api:api-core:jar:0.0.1-20180103.144552-1 from/to proj-repository (http://<nexus_url>/nexus/repository/proj-snapshots): unexpected end of stream
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:895)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$PutTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:743)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.put(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:311)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink.close(HttpConnection.java:314)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.close(RealBufferedSink.java:241)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink$1.close(RealBufferedSink.java:209)
    at com.google.common.io.Closer.close(Closer.java:214)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$FileSource.copyTo(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:147)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient$2.writeTo(OkHttpAetherClient.java:141)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:887)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:749)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:268)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:224)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:195)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.execute(OkHttpAetherClient.java:167)
    at io.takari.aether.okhttp.OkHttpAetherClient.put(OkHttpAetherClient.java:161)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:715)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.put(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:332)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Which Maven versions do you use? Are you running on plain command line or running from within CI solutions like Jenkins ? Do you have a proxy/apache in front of Nexus? Furthermore you using  Takari ?

Comment: Hello Khmarbaise, I am using apache-maven-3.5.0 and running the command from inside eclipse.

Comment: The only difference I see is, the remote nexus repo is uses https.

Comment: Just tested - uploading release versions to a release repository (another maven hosted repo on the same nexus) works fine. The error occurs only for snapshots deployed to snapshots repository.

Comment: First try on plain command line and not from inside Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou khmarbaise for the pointers.
Turned out the nexus had a proxy in front which was limiting the size of jars that could be uploaded.
This is a spring boot applicaiton creating a fat jar. Hence it was failing.

Obviously, I didnt face the issue when i was running a locally hosted nexus and was unable to decipher this from the exception stack trace.

The issue is resovled now, after changing the size limits in the proxy.